# Can't acess SonarQube: not a valid locale

Tags: configuration, sonarqube

After having downloaded sonarqube, I start the server and try to access it at http://localhost:9000. Logs show that server is started.
I have however an error:

```
2015.03.11 14:39:02 INFO  web[o.s.s.app.Logging]  Web server is started
2015.03.11 14:39:03 ERROR web[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade]  Fail to render: http://localhost:9000/
"fr" is not a valid locale
    /home/osallou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:284:in `enforce_available_locales!'
    /home/osallou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/config.rb:13:in `locale='
    /home/osallou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:43:in `locale='
....
```

fr_FR is in my locale (ubuntu), and my default locale is en_US

I do not understand why it takes french (but why not), but I need to fix the conf/startup issue. I do not see any locale config in sonar.conf.

Thanks

Comment: I found the issue, at least partially. I have an rvm environment, and sonar loads some of my rvm gems. Seems there are some conflicts.

Answer (score 13):

SonarQube uses an older version of the [i18n gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/i18n/) (see the `web/WEB-INF/gems/gems` directory).
If you disable the `rvm`, Sonar should work fine.

#### Disable rvm

`$ rvm use system`

Answer (score 5):

You can just create a new gemset & use that instead. The sonarqube zip file comes with all the gems that are needed.

```
rvm gemset create sonar
rvm gemset use sonar
```

Comment: This is the best answer so far, at least for RVM users.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue but I didnt find an answer. I didnt track down why it was happen but I have a work around

All I did was

`gem uninstall i18n`

`sonar restart`

and it worked. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add to my .bashrc file for the sonar user the following lines to access SQ.

unset GEM_HOME
unset GEM_PATH